# Making a deepcopy of custom class object in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, deep-copy

I am trying to implement something analogous to how if `x` is a list then `y = list(x)` should be a deepcopy of `x`.

So far I have the following class code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        if isinstance(foo, CustomClass):
            self = deepcopy(foo)
        else:
            self._foo = foo
```

Now if I run

```
A = CustomClass(bar)
B = CustomClass(A)
print(B._foo)
```

I receive an error `AttributeError: 'CustomClass' object has no attribute '_foo'`. I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong here. If for example I were to add the line `print(self._foo)` inside the if statement I would see that the deepcopy was successfully assigned to self. Is there a way to implement this deepcopy functionality?

Comment: because ```B``` satisfies the if statement ```if isinstance(foo, CustomClass)``` so ```self._foo``` is never created

Comment: @coderoftheday Sorry I don't fully understand. I guess I'm a little lost as to why `self = deepcopy(A)` does not copy the attribute `A._foo` over to `B`.

Comment: But ```A``` is an instance of ```CustomClass``` so why would ```self._foo``` be created

Comment: Assigning to `self` has absolutely no effect outside of the function (and has absolutely no effect inside the function in this case, since it does not subsequently use `self`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As have been said in the comments, assigning to `self` does not help. The issue is that when `__init__(...)` is called, the class is already created and a reference is kept outside the class (i.e. by the Python interpreter/runtime). And, since `__init__(...)` does not return anything (and specifically not its own reference) there is no way to change the external reference from there, which your attempt to `deepcopy` does.

The object creation in Python, when calling e.g. `CustomClass(foo)`, is actually a two step process. First, before the call to `__init__(...)` the runtime calls another, statical method on the class, namely `__new__(...)`. This is where the actual object is constructed and this class method actually *do* return a reference to the object. Thus, in theory it should be possible to do a `deepcopy` in the `__new__(...)`method (if you know how to do it). However, after the call to `__new__(...)` returns, the runtime will continue the creation process and call the `__init__(...)` method. Thus, in this case you would also need to ensure that this call does not change anything in the newly copied object.

A simpler way, though, is to allow the system to create a new object for you (by its automatic call to `__new__(...)`) and then "form" the new image into a (deep copied) image of the orignal object. This can be done by deep copying all the attributes of the original object and put them in the new one. If all attributes are known, this can be done by explicitly listing them and assign the (deepcopied) calues to them:

```
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        if isinstance(foo, CustomClass):
            # if foo is CustomClass, deepcopy all its attributes
            self._foo = deepcopy(foo._foo)
            # return to not perform "normal" initialization
            return
        # This will only execute if foo is _not_ a CustomClass object
        self._foo = foo
```

However, this approach is a bit fragile, as it requires that no attribute is forgotten in the copying process, and that no new attributes are added dynamically (or they will not be copied) if e.g. someone is doing somethin like

```
cc = CustomClass(4)
cc.dynamic = 5
```

`cc.dynmaic` will not be copied (whereas `deepcopy` will). A better approach is therefore to use the internal dictionary that keep a reference to all attributes, whenever they are created:

```
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        if isinstance(foo, CustomClass):
            # if foo is CustomClass, deepcopy all its attributes
            self.__dict__ = {key: deepcopy(value) for key, value in foo.__dict__.items()}
            # return to not perform "normal" initialization
            return
        # This will only execute if foo is _not_ a CustomClass object
        self._foo = foo
```

Here the internal `__dict__` of the object is used. It references all attributes, including any that has been dynamically added, and then I `deepcopy` each of them and assign them to our newly created object, mimicing the behavior of a "normal" `deepcopy`call.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, much appreciated! :)